# Craft's answer to {switch} from EE

Tags: templating

Does Craft have an answer to ExpressionEngine's `{switch}` tag?

```
{switch="classOne|classTwo|classThree"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do the same in Craft using Twig's [cycle function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/cycle.html):

```
{% set myClasses = ['classOne', 'classTwo', 'classThree'] %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ cycle(myClasses, loop.index0) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation site

```
{% switch matrixBlock.type %}

    {% case "text" %}

        {{ matrixBlock.textField | markdown }}

    {% case "image" %}

        {{ matrixBlock.image[0].getImg() }}

    {% default %}

        <p>A font walks into a bar.</p>
        <p>The bartender says, “Hey, we don’t serve your type in here!”</p>

{% endswitch %}
```

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/switch

Comment: Despite the fact that the names are the same, those two functions do very different things. To be fair, EE is grossly misusing the `switch` terminology.